# breaking loop with keypress in linux c

Tags: c, keypress

I need to write a program in C language which will be doing something like this:
For example, when I will press "a", terminal will be writing that typed character in the unending loop like this:  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...until another key, for example "b" will be pressed. Final output should look like this: aaaaaaaaabbbbbbq (q should terminate the program).
My code here:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int c;
    static struct termios staryTermios, novyTermios;


    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &staryTermios);

    novyTermios = staryTermios;
    novyTermios.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &novyTermios);
    while ((c = getchar()) != 'q') {
        putchar(c);
    }

    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &staryTermios);

    return 0;
}
```

this version writes the typed characters only once and then it waits for another keypress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will need two threads which will both be accessing a common variable. The job of one thread would be to continuously print the common variable. The job of the second would be to wait for input from the keyboard and update the variable accordingly.

Comment: thanks, but I am new in C programming and I don't know how to use threads.
Friend of mine suggested me to use read() function instead od getchar(). But I have no idea how to timeout the read() function or something like that

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the result you want, you need to make the standard input non-blocking.  You can do that with this minor adaptation of your code.  It worked fine on Mac OS X 10.7.5. Note that `getchar()` returns EOF when there's no character ready to read (which will be most of the time; neither you nor I can type fast enough to matter to a modern computer). I'm mildly concerned that on some systems, once `getchar()` has returned EOF once when there was no character to read, it might never return anything other than EOF again, but that wasn't a problem for Mac OS X.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void err_exit(const char *msg);

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    int oc = '\0';
    struct termios staryTermios, novyTermios;
    int oflags, nflags;

    if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &staryTermios) != 0)
        err_exit("tcgetattr() failed");

    novyTermios = staryTermios;
    novyTermios.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &novyTermios) != 0)
        err_exit("tcsetattr() failed to set standard input");

    oflags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL);
    if (oflags < 0)
        err_exit("fcntl() F_GETFL failed");

    nflags = oflags;
    nflags |= O_NONBLOCK;
    if (fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, nflags) == -1)
        err_exit("fcntl() F_SETFL failed");

    while ((c = getchar()) != 'q')
    {
        if (c != EOF)
            oc = c;
        if (oc != '\0')
            putchar(oc);
    }

    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &staryTermios) != 0)
        err_exit("tcsetattr() failed to reset standard input");

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

static void err_exit(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(1);
}
```