# How to automatically press 'ENTER' key after every input in C?

Tags: c

I was making a software where, every time after the User would enter a number, automatically *ENTER* key will be pressed (I mean, The value will be assigned without pressing *ENTER* ).

**Sample code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int i, num[10];

for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);  

    /*this is where I need help. 
    Every time after typing a single number, the program should store the value
    and move on to next position without requiring the user to press ENTER. How do I
    do that ? */
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in pure C I'm afraid. Have a frustrating upvote.

Comment: Input from the console is buffered. Meaning that your program won't get fed any input until enter is pressed.  Google for "raw i/o" to learn more about how to do this for your particular os.

Comment: If you just want a single digit, use %c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [breaking loop with keypress in linux c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310848/breaking-loop-with-keypress-in-linux-c)

Comment: Is the 'single number' you refer to a single digit (`0` .. `9`), or can it include multi-digit numbers (`10` .. `∞`)?  With single digits, it is easier because you can't tell you've reached the end of a number until you type something that isn't a digit (space, newline, etc).  This is partly a question of terminology, of course.  You may need to read about [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342/).

Comment: You cannot in pure C. Full stop. That being said different OS can offer different ways. It is possible both in Windows and in Unix or Linux, but not in a portable way. Comments above are for Unix way, conio is the DOS/Windows way.

Comment: As there is no standard C way, you need to specify operating system and on Windows also compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [getch()](https://www.c-lang.thiyagaraaj.com/archive/c-blog/use-of-getch-getche-and-getchar-in-c) function, but only reads a number from 0 to 9.
Next, you can convert to int by using `(int)(ch)-48)`, example:

```
char ch;
ch=getch();
printf("%d", (ch - '0'));

/*You can do this too*/
// printf("%d", ((int)(ch)-48));
```

*The number 48 is the '0' in the ascii table.*

Comment: That is conio.h function. Not really very recommended, because it's not standard snd iw kind if DOS/Windows terminal specific...

Comment: @hyde There is no non-platform-specific way to obtain this functionality.

Comment: @Sneffel Yes, but conio.h is still not very good option. For example, last MSVC to have it, seems to be 2015, looking at versions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x2hy4cx.aspx. At the very least, answer should mention where getch() comes from.

Comment: @hyde You right, but I think it's the only way to do this in C.

Comment: @FábioMorais Of course it isn't the only way. You could use win32 API directly, for instance (that's what *conio* does internally). Anyway, user does not specify OS or compiler, so there's no way to know if this answer is valid for them or not.

Comment: don't use a magic number like 48. No one knows what it is. And it's not guaranteed to be 48 on other charset. Use `'0'` instead

Comment: no. You're still using the magic number. Use `ch - '0'` instead

Comment: Ok, I used both ways, I think is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid `getch()` from `conio.h` as suggested in the given answer, use `getchar()` from `stdio.h`.